# How to display additional information on each point in a graph in Grafana

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I have Grafana 7.5 with InfluxDB 1.7.8.

The DB is basically storing the size of a container for each image builds, being `build` different every time and an important piece of information.

An example of how the DB looks like:

```
> select * from size
name: size
time                build value version
----                ----  ----- -------
1650440494922639073 1.1   203   0.1
1650440501807252201 1.2   207   0.1
1650440501807252201 1.3   208   0.1
```

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT "value" FROM "size" WHERE "version" = '0.1' AND $timeFilter
```

and I'm using the Graph to represent the data.

When I place the mouse over the data points, it only displays the value (size) and I would like to show the build as well.

Answer (score 0):

`build` must be a tag (not a field) + you need to group by that `build` tag in your query.

Comment: I am using this command to post the data: `curl -i -XPOST "http://localhost:8086/write?db=data" --data-binary "size,version=0.1,build=1.1 value=203"`  Aren't those tags?